# Prolog: Return list of Y from facts where X = x

Tags: prolog

I'm pretty new to Prolog and can't wrap my head around a certain problem.
Say I have a couple of Facts *fact(X,Y)*:
fact(a, m).
fact(b, m).
fact(c, n).
fact(x, q).
fact(x, y).
fact(x, z).

I would like to create a list of all Y of facts with a specific X.
For Example:
?- getList(x, LIST).
LIST = [q,y,z].

q,y,z are returned because they are found in facts where X = x.

Is there a quick way to do this? I have tried using recursion to iterate through all fact(x, Y) and append each Y but I couldn't make it work.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [findall/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=findall/3) to obtain all the solutions for your query and gather a list with the template you desire.

In your example it should be:

```
findall(Y, fact(x, Y), LIST).
```

Comment: Actually, use setof/3 or bagof/3 which properly fail if there is no solution whereas findall does the "procedural thing" and succeeds with the empty list.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer: I actually believe the student can understand more easily findall/3 and then go on with setof/3 or bagof/3 if desired. I also think he wants an empty list if no solution is found instead of failure.

Comment: You guys seriusly rock, thank you! Can't believe I didn't find this myself.